# Set .htaccess rule only on remote server for PHP app?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a rule in my app (in `/.htaccess`) that sets a htpassword for access to the site. We need this on the *remote* server, because we don't want anyone except us seeing it.

However, on the local server, I don't want to deal with the htpassword mess. Is there any way that I can make the rule valid only if the domain isn't "localhost", or something of a similar variety?

I'm using PHP as a backend language, so if there's a way I can solve it with PHP, that would be great.

Thanks for any help in advance.

**Edit** - The offending code:

```
authtype basic
authgroupfile /dev/null
authuserfile /path/to/htpassword
authname "Secure Area"
require user username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html#satisfy

```
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName intranet
  AuthUserFile /www/passwd/users
  AuthGroupFile /www/passwd/groups
  Require group customers
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from internal.com
  Satisfy any
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} your_remote_hostname
```

Add that condition in (obviously replacing the relevant part with your hostname) before the `RewriteRule` line.

Comment: It's not a `RewriteRule` though, it's an authtype/name/require user. I've edited my code above to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) directive:

> Require all granted
>       Access is allowed unconditionally. Require all denied
>       Access is denied unconditionally. Require env env-var [env-var] ...
>       Access is allowed only if one of the given environment variables is set. Require method http-method [http-method] ...
>       Access is allowed only for the given HTTP methods. Require expr expression
>       Access is allowed if expression evaluates to true.
>
> Some of the allowed syntaxes provided by mod_authz_user,
>   mod_authz_host, and mod_authz_groupfile are:
>
> ```
> Require user userid [userid] ...
>     Only the named users can access the resource.
> Require group group-name [group-name] ...
>     Only users in the named groups can access the resource.
> Require valid-user
>     All valid users can access the resource.
> Require ip 10 172.20 192.168.2
>     Clients in the specified IP address ranges can access the resource.
> ```

```
authtype basic
authgroupfile /dev/null
authuserfile /path/to/htpassword
authname "Secure Area"
require user username
require ip 10.10.10.10
```